# Get values from webmarkupcontainer in wicket

Tags: wicket

I have a WebMarkUpContainer in which i have dropdown , textfiled and the submit button.
On submit i want the values of the dropdown and textfield in an another WebMarkUpContainer.
Can any one please help me how to get the values .

Regards,
Sharath

Comment: Can you provide some code? Did you use Wicket markup elements (TextField, DropDownChoice, Form)?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a model to the form containing your DropDown and TextField and share the model object between the two Containers. The model and model objects get updated on submit and if both containers share the same model object (or model) they share the values and you're done.